# passing json array to ajax call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

guys i know its dummy questions but i spent hours on this and cant reach .. I am trying to pass a JSON array to JSP via an AJAX call in another JS file. It is giving me a 404 error. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```js
function GridLibrary(fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

GridLibrary.prototype = {
    setFileName : function(fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    },
    getFileName : function() {
        return this.fileName;
    }
};

GridLibrary.prototype.display = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : this.getFileName(),
        dataType: "json",
        error : function(that, e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert("found");
        }
    });
};
```

```java
var Json = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "age" : 10,
    "feedback": "feedback1"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "age" : 90,
    "feedback": "feedback2"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "name3",
    "age" : 30,
    "feedback": "feedback3"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "name4",
    "age" : 50,
    "feedback": "feedback4"
}];

new GridLibrary(Json).display();
```

Comment: What is `data` passed in the constructor? and you should remove the `()` from the ajax: `url : this.getFileName,`

Comment: the data array .. as shown below

Comment: isn't `data` should be `Json`? and then it just doesn't make sense to add data as a `url` in the ajax.

Comment: yes you are right ..  i just mistaken in wrirting .. but still the same problem occurs

Comment: what is the `method` that you send to this request? `POST || GET`

Comment: nothing i am writing the array in jsp so i think no need for it

Comment: see this is invalid `url:[{},{},{}]`

Comment: so any suggestions to make it valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a valid url to send the values to the backend:

```js
function GridLibrary(url, data) {
  this.url = url;
  this.data = data;
}

GridLibrary.prototype = {
  setData: function(data) {
    this.data = data;
  },
  getData: function() {
    return this.data;
  },
  setUrl:function(url){ this.url = url; },
  getUrl:function(){ return this.url; },

  display : function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.getUrl, // <----the url where you want to send the data
      data:this.getData, //<----should be the array data
      dataType: "json",
      contentType:"application/json", // <----add this contentType
      error: function(that, e) {
        console.log(e);
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("found");
      }
    });
  }
};

var url = '/url/to/send',
    data = [{}....];

new GridLibrary(url, data).display();
```

Comment: which line @mmmm? this isn't helping. may be you should add `contentType:"application/json"` too to the ajax.

Comment: @MichaelGeary  so no other suggestions for this parse error ?

Comment: @Jai no other suggestions for the parse error i have ?

Comment: What does the parse error point to? Is it the `display =`? Change that to `display:`. Then you'll also need the actual data in the `data = []`.